# How to repeat one loop in foreach

Tags: c#, for-loop

Hi guys how can you repeat one iteration in a foreach?

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("file.txt"))
{
     // now line == "account", next line == "account1"
     if (line.Contains("a"))
         //next loop take "account1";
     else
        // need to set that next loop will take line == "account" again
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: You can't; use `for` instead.

Comment: This example will just get stuck in a loop reading the line 'account' over and over...?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.  Can you explain your overall intent for the code, as this sample seems very flawed?

Comment: I would be tempted to say that while this question is not very well expressed, this is probably not an XY problem - it is a "classical" thing that you may want to have in your toolbox: You want to have a while loop, but conditionally potentially execute each one multiple times. For loop is not always an option as your input might be just an IEnumerable. Classic case would be to have a list of "tasks" to do and you might want to try each on let's say 3 times in case you have a transient error.

Answer (score 11):

While I don't fully understand your example, I think I understand your question.  I had the same problem and was able to come up with a solution:  include a while loop within the foreach.  In your example it would look like this:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("file.txt"))
{
    bool repeat = true;
    while (repeat)
    {
        // now line == "account", next line == "account1"
        if (line.Contains("a"))
        {
            //do your logic for a break-out case
            repeat = false;
        }
        else 
        {
          //do your logic for a repeat case on the same foreach element
          //in this instance you'll need to add an "a" to the line at some point, to avoid an infinite loop.
        }
     }
}
```

I know I'm very late to the game, but hopefully this will be helpful for anyone else who stumbles in here with the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to change your code, assuming it only has an `if/else` construct in the loop.

When the `if` condition evaluates to `true` the `else` will not execute and the loop resumes.

In a more complex where you want to immediately resume the loop and ensure nothing else following the condition executes, use the [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/923ahwt1.aspx) statement:

> The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the enclosing while, do, for, or foreach statement in which it appears.

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("file.txt"))
{
     // now line == "account", next line == "account1"
     if (line.Contains("a"))
         continue;
     else
        // need to set that next loop will take line == "account" again

     // more stuff that we don't want to execute if line.Contains("a")
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm not sure if that's what he wants. If the else body is `print line` he might want to print "account" lots of times. You need additional code to do that.

Comment: @nmat - On additional reading, what he seems to want makes no sense. If he has the line he wants, why not just operate on it and be done with it?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Besides, it will create an endless loop. We need more details

Answer (score 3):

I guess this might also helpful if someone else come

```
for (int i = 0; i < inventoryTimeBlocks.Count; i++)
{
 if (line.Contains("a"))
     //next loop take "account1";
 else
 {
   if(i > 0)
   {
    i = i - 1;
    continue;
   }
 }
}
```